# mantain session between 2 instgances of tomcat

Tags: session, tomcat

How to mantain session b/w 2 different instances of tomcat.

*not asking about sticky session*
*do not want to use any token machenisum like fedrated login/o-outh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the formal answer to this should be:

Use the session replication mechanism. For example, for Tomcat 7 is described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html).

So if you know that the application is very small (say, less than 100 users, although it really depends on the data you're planning to store there) you can safely use it, and stop reading my answer here :)

However, in my opinion, small applications tend to grow, the number or users tends to increase, so the best would be not to maintain the session at all :). Because if you need session, this means that you store on server the information about the client. So when the number of client grows much, you won't be able to maintain that.

An alternative is:

1. Store the session information in some very-fast storage, for example [Redis](http://redis.io/)
2. Maintain some identifier of the user (the chances are that you already have one) and just query redis for the data. Redis has TTLs, so the data can be removed from Redis automatically.

The advantage is that the solution like this is much more scalable, so it can easily handle literally millions of records, while maintaining this at the level of JVM will make it impossible to scale.